# Android - Parse Query: Limit 1 object per user

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a Parse query of Messages, right now it returns all the Message the current user follows.

I would like it to limit it to only 1 message per user, so when a user send a message, it replaces the old one.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> receiver = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");
        receiver.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
        receiver.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> sender = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");
        sender.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
        sender.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());



        List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
        queries.add(receiver);
        queries.add(sender);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
        mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {


                if (e == null) {

                    // We found messages!
                    mMessages = messages;


                    if (isFragmentUIActive()) {
                        if (recyclerView.getAdapter() == null) {
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(new InboxAdapter(recyclerView.getContext(), mMessages, R.layout.message_item));
                            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        } else {
                            // refill the adapter!
                            Log.i("Refill", "todo");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use [setLimit(1)](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#setLimit(int))

> `setLimit(int newLimit)`: Controls the maximum number of results that are returned.

Code example :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> receiver = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(getQuery());
receiver.setLimit(1);

public ParseQuery<T> getQuery() {
  return query;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i get a error. "                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot have limits in sub queries of an 'OR' query"

Comment: Hello, i get a another error. "Error:(149, 48) error: no suitable constructor found for ParseQuery(ParseQuery)
constructor ParseQuery.ParseQuery(Class<ParseObject>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ParseQuery cannot be converted to Class<ParseObject>)
constructor ParseQuery.ParseQuery(String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ParseQuery cannot be converted to String)
constructor ParseQuery.ParseQuery(Builder<ParseObject>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ParseQuery cannot be converted to Builder<ParseObject>)"